# Question about injective map on subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with $N \lhd G$, and let $\pi:G \rightarrow G/N$ be the canonical surjection.

Show that $\Lambda:\text{Sub}(G;N) \rightarrow \text{Sub}(G/N)$ so that $H \mapsto \pi(H)$ is an injection between the subgroups $H \leq G$ which contain $N$ and the set of all subgroups of $G/N$.

**Attempt:**

Assume $\Lambda(H_1)=\Lambda(H_2)$ for subgroups $H_1,H_2 \leq G$. Then $\pi(H_1)=\pi(H_2)$ so that $H_1/N = H_2/N$. But since $\pi$ is a surjection, we have that $\pi^{-1}(H_1/N) = \pi^{-1}(H_2/N)$, hence $H_1 = H_2$ and $\Lambda$ is injective.

I feel like this proof is too short and doesn't describe the injection enough, any help?

Comment: I can't understand why would anyone downvote this question...+1

Comment: your use of $\;\cong\;$ is confusing as it *should* be equality in the three instances...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea: show that in fact

$$\pi^{-1}\left(H/N\right)=\left\{x\in G\;;\;\pi(x)\in H/N\;\right\}$$

This way you'd quickly get a double inclusion which will lead you at once to $\;H_1=H_2\;$ ,  using your notation.

Comment: What do you mean by "show" - this is the very definition of the preimage operator.

Comment: I'm happy you realize that, @MartinBrandenburg . Hopefully the OP will, too.